# Google Drive API - Example code is not working

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-oauth, google-openid, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to use Google API to transfer SharePoint Documents to Google Drive using dot net. For that to happen I want to use this [link Google Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs).

I have followed every little piece of information. It states in beginning "Complete the steps described in the rest of this page, and in about five minutes you'll have a simple Drive app that uploads a file to Google Drive" but it is not true.

I am trying to run this sample example since yesterday but failed.

```
// Register the authenticator and create the service
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
```

So it seems that this code example is outdated and Google APIs have been upgraded.

Here comes the warning

> [Obsolete("GoogleAuthenticationServer is not supported any more and it's going to be removed in 1.7.0-beta. Consider using the new Google.Apis.Auth NuGet package which supports .NET 4, .NET for Windows Store apps, Windows Phone 7.5 and 8 and Portable Class Libraries as well")]

Another code

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
Authenticator = auth
});
```

And the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient' to 'Google.Apis.Http.IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Then I was looking for [latest release samples] there I found the [source files](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.7.0-beta/Generated/ZipFiles/google-api-dotnet-client-1.7.0-beta.source.zip).
I was not able able to run the sample also.

Here I was successfully authenticated but then had error for redirect Uri
My Client_Secrets.JSON looks like, as you can see I have set default redirect Uri to `http://localhost/`.

```
{"web":{"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","client_secret":"secret","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","client_email":email","redirect_uris":["http://localhost/"],"client_x509_cert_url":"aa@developer.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"id","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","javascript_origins":["http://localhost:53404/"]}}
```

Now I can run this application but as mentioned getting error

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>   The redirect URI in the request: [[http://localhost:2430/authorize/]] did not match a registered redirect URI

I really don’t know from where this port number comes and from where this authorize comes. As you can see in my JSON, I have not set anything similar.

I am using VS 2010 SP1 Ultimate and Windows 7 home Basic.

I have tried to give complete information and my end goal is upload document in Google drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples. It's a Task API **ASP.NET** sample. As you can see you need to add several lines of code, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you are following uses an older version of google.apis thats why you are seeing the not supported.  Here are a couple of tutorials on how it works with the new version of the api.

- http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/
- http://daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/

Comment: Thanks for the answer DalmTo,
I have tried the first link you have provided.
It is giving me the same error i have posted  in **BOLD**
I am able to connet with authentication screen of google,but then the issue comes with redirect uri.
again adding it here for your reference.
    
    **The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:4103/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI**

I really dont know from where google Appends Port number and **authorize** string.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo,  can you please help me with some help on solving the above REDIRECT URI Issue. your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The redirect URI needs to be the same one that you have set up in google apis console.

Comment: In google api console-"redirect_uris":["http://localhost/"] as you can find it from the JSON i posted as code block in the question, now when i am running it, some how it is changed to random port number and append itself with authorize string.
like just seconds before when i ran the project it has given me below error.
**The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:4183/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI**
please take not of different portnumber in all above errors

Comment: Been checking.  Theres a diffrence if its a webapp vs a installed app.  I should have realised that.   https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2  I have a meeting now will try and fix it when i get back and post it if you havent figured it out.

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, What i want is a web app which can upload the document to google drive.
After looking at the link provided, i understand that webapp requires MVC, is it true, I can not use plain dotnet?

Comment: Hi @razor,I have seen you asking DaImTo Who are you trying to help? I can message him for you ;)
you can help on this issue.

Comment: Hi, you should use MVC, the alternative is to use regular ASP.NET application. But you should follow our instructions in 1) https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Google_APIs_Console - Section 4 (Web Applications) and 2) https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2#Web_Applications_(using_ASP.NET_MVC). Hope that it makes sense.

Comment: Hi @peleyal, Both the links uses MVC, I want to use plain ASP.NET, is it not possible? there is no simple getting started with asp.net?

Comment: You could but you will have to code it all yourself without using there dll.

Comment: Take a look in this sample - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples. It's ASP.NET (not MVC)

Comment: Thanks peleyal,DaImTo . it is helpful.
@peleyal, can you please add your link as answer instead comment, so I can mark it as answer and it helps other users,they don't have to read 10 comments to get correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the samples Eyal mentions and got that compiling before integrating with my own app.  .Net needs to be 4 although it states it supports higher.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the redirect URI in the google developer console, not in your JSON. In your case, you would want to set it to `http://localhost:2430/authorize/`.